# Ionic firebase once snapshot get weird bugs

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm trying to set something through firebase realtime database using set code but before that, I need to use once snapshot to get value and update it.

When I have an array that contains strings ex.) `array[0] = "aaa"; array[1] = "bbb";` I should be able to get each string but I'm getting only the last element of array.

First of all, the array contained an object like `{ name:"name", num:2, isEmpty:false }` so I tried to fix it to contain only string 
using `array.push("string");` but I still get same bug.

Before using `once('value',snapshot){...}` I had no problem with getting element from array but when I use `once()` I only get last element of array with invalid index.

```
array[0] = 'aaaa'; array[1] ='bbbb';

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  alert(array[i]+' '+i); 
  //this works fine, alerts aaaa 0, bbbb 1   

  firebase.database().ref('/Something/').child(array[i]).child('size').once('value',snap=>{
     alert(array[i]+' '+i); 
     //alerts bbbb 2, bbbb 2, I really don't get the issue, snap.val() works fine tho but only get bbbb's snap.val()
  });
}
```

This is sample code, I tried to set something inside of `once()`, but it only sets for 'bbbb' path's child. It never goes on 'aaaa' path.

it must alert aaaa 0, bbbb 1. but why am I getting bbbb 2, bbbb 2? the index is even invalid the length of the array is 2. I really have no idea about this issue. Please can someone help me out of this one?

*I tried everything I could, changing array,using `on()` instead of `once()`, using `then()` after `once()`, etc.. but by the sample code, it must not have any issues right???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem with 'async' function, anyone who has same issues with me, just make another async function to do something in once()